# Unable to find longest match of string within List<String>

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to find the longest match of strings in a list of strings if my List are:

```
- "1->2"
- "1->2->3"
- "1->2->3->4"
- "5->6"
- "5->6->7"
- "5->6->7->8"
```

So the output should be because this strings contain all of the matches within the same list, I want to discard the remaining matches which fall short:

```
"1->2->3->4"
"5->6->7->8"
```

**Update:**

---

As `1->2` and `1->2->3` are contained in `1->2->3->4`, so I want to discard the less specific ones like `1->2` and `1->2->3` and take the longest match `1->2->3->4`

The paths will always be in order like `1->2->3->4` and not `1->4` or `1->3`.

I am trying like this, but I am getting `enumeration yielded no results`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<(string, i)> flattenedPaths = new List<(string, i)> 
        {
                ("1->2", 0)
                ("1->2->3", 1)
                ("1->2->3->4", 2)
                ("5->6", 3)
                ("5->6->7", 4)
                ("5->6->7->8", 5)
        };

        IEnumerable<string> uniquePaths = GetUniquePaths(flattenedPaths);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<(string, int)> GetUniquePaths(List<(string, int)> Paths)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Paths.Count; i++)
        {
            bool doesMatchContain = Paths.Skip(i)
                                    .Any(x => x.Item1.Contains(Paths[i].Item1));

            if (!doesMatchContain)
                yield return Paths[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can we discard `2 -> 3` when we have `1->2->3->4`?

Comment: Your `Paths.Skip(i)` should be `Paths.Skip(i+1)`. As it is, you will always compare the current iteration to the current iteration (which will always be true) instead of the *rest* of the collection.

Comment: One edge case to consider with your `Contains` approach. Consider what might happen if these two entries are both there. `2->3` and `31->32->33`. I suspect your logic will believe the first is contained in the second (when it isn't).

Comment: @mjwills in that case it would fail because `32->33` has `2->3` contained in it.

Comment: That is exactly my point. Your logic would say it is part of it **when it clearly isn't** (`2->3` aren't in `31->32->33` - they are completely different numbers). The issue here is that your data representation isn't great. Don't use strings (or at least convert the strings to a better representation). Each path is really a pair of numbers - a lower number and a higher number (e.g. 1->2->3->4 is 1 and 4). When you model it that way, it is much easier to solve - and you don't have to worry about the 32->33 problem.

Answer (score 1):

Below is one approach you may wish to try.

`betterData` is your existing data, but projected into a more usable form - where the upper and lower bounds of the range are integers rather than strings.

*The `Substring` and `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf` code is brittle - but will work for your current sample data - feel free to harden it up with checks for `-1` etc.*

Once we have a list of data with those upper and lower bounds set, we use `RemoveAll` to delete any entries from the list which are **within** a 'wider' range (e.g. 2-3 is **within** 1-4).

*Note also that `betterData.ToList()` is used to allow us to iterate over the list **while modifying it**. There are fancier ways of doing the same effect - but they are slightly more error prone so I've gone for the dumb but simple approach here.*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", uniquePaths.Select(z => z.Item1 + " " + z.Item2)));
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<(string, int)> flattenedPaths = new List<(string, int)>
        {
                ("1->2", 0),
                ("1->2->3", 1),
                ("1->2->3->4", 2),
                ("5->6", 3),
                ("5->6->7", 4),
                ("5->6->7->8", 5),
        };

    private static IEnumerable<(string, int)> uniquePaths = GetUniquePaths(flattenedPaths);

    private static IEnumerable<(string, int)> GetUniquePaths(List<(string, int)> Paths)
    {
        var betterData = Paths
            .Select(z => new
            {
                Number = z.Item2,
                Value = z.Item1,
                Lower = int.Parse(z.Item1.Substring(0, z.Item1.IndexOf("-"))),
                Upper = int.Parse(z.Item1.Substring(z.Item1.LastIndexOf("-") + 2))
            })
            .OrderByDescending(z => z.Value.Length).ThenByDescending(z => z.Upper).ThenBy(z => z.Lower).ToList();

        foreach (var entry in betterData.ToList())
        {
            betterData.RemoveAll(z => z != entry && z.Lower >= entry.Lower && z.Upper <= entry.Upper);
        }

        return betterData.Select(x => (x.Value, x.Number));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your given list

```
List<string> list= new List<string>
{
    "1->2",
    "1->2->3",
    "1->2->3->4",
    "5->6",
    "5->6->7",
    "5->6->7->8"
};
```

The LINQ query would be

```
var result = list
    .Where(s => !list.Any(s2 => s2 != s && s2.IndexOf(s) == 0))
    .ToList();
```

`result` contains `"1->2->3->4"` and `"5->6->7->8"`

Answer (score -1):

if the input is in order and if you would like to find the longest sequence of that containing that string then follow below code,

```
class Program
{
    string output;
    public void initalize(string findlongestcontainof)
    {
        int length = 0;

        List<string> inputs = new List<string>();
        inputs.Add("1->2->3");
        inputs.Add("1->2->3->4");
        inputs.Add("1->2->3->4->5->6");
        inputs.Add("1->2->3->4->5");

        foreach(string s in inputs)
        {
            if(s.Contains(findlongestcontainof))
            {
                if(s.Length > length)
                {
                    length = s.Length;
                    output = s;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.initalize("1->2");
        Console.WriteLine(p.output);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: It simply provides the longest of the sequence containing the input string, one question does string "33 -> 34" means  i should be considering it for 1,2...34 or simply 33,34 if 1,2...34 the above code doesn't support

Comment: So it returns both `"1->2->3->4"` and `"5->6->7->8"` for that shown set of inputs?